# Hibernate and Spring Annotation @OneToMany unmapped class error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I'm using Spring 3 with Hibernate 3 and getting this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or
>   @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:
>   cz.dagoo.dros.models.Invoice.invoiceItems[cz.dagoo.dros.models.InvoiceItem]

I've tried everything what I found but I'm not able to solve this problem.

How is it possible that some class is unmapped?

Invoice class:
[image: Invoice class]

InvoiceItem class:

[image: InvoiceItem class]

Hibernate.xml:
[image: Hibernate.xml]

BeanLocations.xml:
[image: BeanLocations.xml]

My project files:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception tells you: `cz.dagoo.dros.models.InvoiceItem` is not mapped as an entity. To solve this issue you should add the missing `@Entity`-annotation on InvoiceItem.

Comment: Thank you! First I was using XML, annotations came later and I forgot to add Entity and Table to InvoiceItem.